# how to use symfony controller variables in frontend js?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

Say I have a controller like this:

```
public function showAction(Request $request, $id, $context = array())
{
    $url = $this->getPlayUrl($id, $context);

    //some code here}
```

I want to use the variable $url in a frontend js file like this :

```
var html = '<iframe src=\''+ url +'\' name=\'viewerIframe\' id=\'viewerIframe\' width=\'100%\'allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen height=\'100%\' style=\'border:0px\'></iframe>';
```

How am I supposed to make this happen? For the code above ,it gave me 'undefined url' error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to have your template call a controller action (so you can pass parameters as required), for example, like this example for using highchart.js:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:script')) }}
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

In the controller it looks like this:

```
public function scriptAction() {
    $reports = $this->get('app.reports');
    $chart = $reports->getDistsFYToDate();

    return $this->render('Default/script.js.twig', array(
                'chart' => $chart,
    ));
}
```

and `script.js.twig` looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Distributions, FY{{ chart.fy }} to date'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [{% for category in chart.categories %}{{category|raw}}{%endfor%}]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Distributions'
            }
        },
        series: {{ chart.series|raw }}
    };

    $('#linechart').highcharts(options);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In you view add some script tags and assign a javascript vraible to the twig variable. Don't forget to quote the twig (if required).

Firstly, I would ensure that the $url always had a value;

```
return $this->render('MyWebBundle:Player:show.html.twig', array(
        'file'             => $file,
        'url'              => (empty($url)) ? '' : $url,
        'context'          => $context,
        'player'           => $player,
        'agentInWhiteList' => $agentInWhiteList
    ));
```

Something like;

```
<script>
var jsVar = '{{ url }}';
var html = false;

if (jsVar.length > 0) {
    html = '<iframe src=\''+ jsVar +'\' name=\'viewerIframe\' id=\'viewerIframe\' width=\'100%\'allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen height=\'100%\' style=\'border:0px\'></iframe>';
}

// test html !== false before using it
</script>
```

Comment: put it where it fits best, if that bit of js is just in a single view put it in there. It all depneds on your twig layout (extends, includes, blocks, etc..)

Comment: I think the best way to test it is to put it inside a footer block which is shared by the whole site,but still, it gives me 'ReferenceError: jsVar is not defined-----var html = '<iframe src=\''+ jsVar +'\' name=\'viewerIframe\' id=\'viewerIframe\...
 '

Comment: Updated answer to answer some of your questions

Comment: thank you ,but it's still not working .I must say that 'show.html.twig' is irrelevant ,so are the  variables passed to it. I just want to use the $url in a js like the way it is being used in show.html.twig'.

Comment: just updated the question so u can get a better thought.

Comment: better view, I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better if you use HTML5 data attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes